# string parameter from CLR to native c++ dll

Tags: visual-c++, dll, clr, marshalling, unmanaged

Hi I have a native code dll

Native.dll:

```
#if defined EXPORTDLL // inside DLL
#define DLL_EXPORT __declspec(dllexport)
#else // outside DLL
#define DLL_EXPORT __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

.....

DLL_EXPORT struct1* SomeMethod(uint16_t num1, std::string str1, std::string str2)
{
....
}
```

Then in my managed/CLR I am marshalling this:

```
[DllImport("Native.dll", EntryPoint = "?SomeMethod@@YAPAVstruct1@someSpace@@GV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@0@Z", CallingConvention = CallingConvention::Cdecl)]
struct1* SomeMethod(uint16_t num1, [In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType::LPStr)]String^  str1, [In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType::LPStr)] String^ str2);
```

And later calling this from the managed code:

```
String^ str1 = gcnew String("1223568");
String^ str2 = gcnew String("1.2.3.5");
SomeMethod(1, str1, str2);
```

I can see in the native dll, the str1 value is "1.2.3.5" and the str2 value is badptr.

Can someone tell me what I have to change to get the values passed correctly over to the native dll's arguments please?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your [DllImport] directive is not valid, there is no automatic conversion from String^ to std::string.   You have to take care of the conversion yourself, [use marshal_as](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384865.aspx).  You do not need a [DllImport] at all in C++/CLI, just a prototype declaration.

Comment: Thanks Hans. After I changed my argument type to  const char * (referring to your link) it works.

Comment: Sure, the pinvoke marshaller knows C.  Just not C++.  Still not a very good reason to use [DllImport], C++ interop is more efficient.  Sometimes a *lot* more efficient, not here since string conversions are expensive  Using const wchar_t* is quite sensible, easily done with pin_ptr<>.

Comment: Sorry I am new to dll, interop and marshalling. Can you explain a little please? Cos I have a struct pointer with value types of int and string. And the return pointer shows random values to the struct members which is a combination of integers and string.. I can't find much information for C++ clr calling unmanged c++. Most are on C# calling unmanaged c++.